# Need Help in fixing the infinite loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, chai, treenode

I have the following logic which when I run it in a standalone jsbin it works fine and returns the result.
The code just deserialize the string to tree objects

My requirement is to get the node information in a string format like "1,2,3,4" and then output the node in binary tree structure: 1 for root, 2 for root.left, 3 for root.right, 4 for root.left.left, etc...

But when I call this using node.js using a require command, the while loop is going forever and its not returning the values..

I am new to node.js.

please help

standalone jsbin script
link for below code which runs in jsbin

### http://jsbin.com/tukigaq/edit?js,console,output

```js
(function(exports) {
  'use strict';

  console.clear();

  var createTree = function(treeString) {

    var createTreeNode = function(value) {
      var TreeNode = function(value) {
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
        this.val = value;
      };
      return new TreeNode(value);
    };

    var treeStringSplit = treeString.split(',');
    var root = createTreeNode(treeStringSplit[0]);
    var q = [];
    q.push(root);

    var i = 1;
    while (q.length > 0) {
      var node = q.shift();

      if (node == null)
        continue;

      if (treeStringSplit[i] !== '#') {
        node.left = createTreeNode(treeStringSplit[i]);
        q.push(node.left);
      } else {
        node.left = null;
        q.push(null);
      }

      i++;

      if (treeStringSplit[i] !== '#') {
        node.right = createTreeNode(treeStringSplit[i]);
        q.push(node.right);
      } else {
        node.right = null;
        q.push(null);
      }
      i++;
    }

    return root;
  }

  console.log(createTree("1,#,2,3,4"));


})(typeof window === 'undefined' ? module.exports : window)
```

How  I am calling this in the test method

```
  var expect = require('chai').expect;
  var helper = require('../index');

  describe('createTree', function() {
      test createTree function
       it('should create a tree for the structure', function() {
           var result = helper.createTree("1,2,3");
           expect(result.val).to.equal(1);
           expect(result.left.val).to.equal(2);
           expect(result.right.val).to.equal(2);
       });
       it('should create a tree for the structure', function() {
           var result = helper.createTree("1,#");
           expect(result.val).to.equal(1);
           expect(result.left.val).to.equal(null);
           expect(result.right.val).to.equal(null);
       });
   });
```

Comment: Warning to everyone: Running the stack snippet also loops.

Comment: Why do you start with `i = 1`? Array indexes start at `0`.

Comment: I already created root with - var root = createTreeNode(treeStringSplit[0]);

Comment: For what it's worth, it looks like your script doesn't loop forever on jsbin because jsbin recognizes that it will loop forever and stops the execution.

Comment: The loop ends when `q.length == 0`, but that never happens because you always push a new element onto `q`. You either push `node.left`, `node.right`, or `null`.

Comment: I am shifting the array element inside the loop - var node = q.shift();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're shifting the array in the beginning, but then you're pushing multiple times to the array on each pass through the loop.

You shift off the first element on each pass, but both of these if statements will add new elements to the array:

```
    if (treeStringSplit[i] !== '#') {
      node.left = createTreeNode(treeStringSplit[i]);
      q.push(node.left);
    } else {
      node.left = null;
      q.push(null);
    }

    i++;

    if (treeStringSplit[i] !== '#') {
      node.right = createTreeNode(treeStringSplit[i]);
      q.push(node.right);
    } else {
      node.right = null;
      q.push(null);
    }

    i++;
```

So you'll always have more elements than you're shifting off. I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish, but you will need some additional control logic in there to either remove more elements from the array or prevent multiple elements from being added on each pass.

**Working Example**

Here's a plunker with a working example of the behavior I think you're trying to achieve: https://jsfiddle.net/abfoxef/25ny62h8/

The binary tree code is not mine, it's adapted from [an excellent resource on computer science in javascript](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/06/09/computer-science-in-javascript-binary-search-tree-part-1/)

**Adapted Original Code**

Here's a snippet (that won't run forever) where you can see what's happening in the array structure:

```js
var createTree = function(treeString) {

  var createTreeNode = function(value) {
    var TreeNode = function(value) {
      this.left = null;
      this.right = null;
      this.val = value;
    };
    return new TreeNode(value);
  };

  var treeStringSplit = treeString.split(',');
  var root = createTreeNode(treeStringSplit[0]);
  var q = [];
  q.push(root);

  var i = 0;
  console.log('What is q in the beginning?', q);
  while (i < 25) {
    var node = q.shift();
    console.log('What is q after shift?', q);
    
    if (node == null)
      continue;

    if (treeStringSplit[i] !== '#') {
      node.left = createTreeNode(treeStringSplit[i]);
      q.push(node.left);
    } else {
      node.left = null;
      q.push(null);
    }

    i++;

    if (treeStringSplit[i] !== '#') {
      node.right = createTreeNode(treeStringSplit[i]);
      q.push(node.right);
    } else {
      node.right = null;
      q.push(null);
    }
    
    i++;
    
    console.log('What is q at the end of the loop', q);
  }

  return root;
}
console.log(createTree("1,#,2,3,4"));
```

Comment: my requirement is to get the node information in a string format like "1,2,3,4" and then output the node in binary tree structure, 1 for root, 2 for root.left, 3 for root.right, 4 for root.left.left

Comment: Yes I fixed the problem in my code.. the counter i is going for ever and keeps adding. so I should limit the counter to the length of the split string.. modified code  - (i < treeStringSplit.length)) condition added to while solves the problem.. Thanks for the solution

Comment: @VinodKrishnan That looks better. I also added a link with an example of another binary tree construction method.